# How iterate and print two dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to java script, I have this two dimensional array where I want to pass these array values to links via for loop. I have posted the code below. Can someone tell me how to do this.

Thanks

```
<script>
    var MiddelEastCountriesArray = [['Benelux', 'NE'], ['Deutschland', 'DE'], ['France', 'FR'], ['Ireland', 'IE'], ['Italia', 'IE'], ['Nordics', 'NO'], ['Middle East', 'ME'], ['United Kingdom', 'UK']];

    for(var i = 0; i < MiddelEastCountriesArray.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < MiddelEastCountriesArray[i].length; j++) {

            document.write("<p><a href='http://www.test.com/" + MiddelEastCountriesArray[0][j] + "/default.aspx'>" + MiddelEastCountriesArray[i][0] + "</a></p>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Expected Output :

```
        <p><a href='http://www.test.com/NE/default.aspx'>Benelux</a></p>
        <p><a href='http://www.test.com/DE/default.aspx'>Deutschland</a></p>
        <p><a href='http://www.test.com/FR/default.aspx'>France</a></p>
        <p><a href='http://www.test.com/IE/default.aspx'>Ireland</a></p>
        ....
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Show us expected output

Comment: Looks like it works, although you might have noticed that you didn't use "j" for anything (and you can remove that loop).  Country name would be MECA[i][0], country code MECA[i][1].  I would rename that array, too much typing!

Comment: Not getting what is the use of inner for-loop if you are getting always 0th element

Comment: I have updated the post. I have added my expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Replace the `""` with `MiddelEastCountriesArray[i][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate inner loop. try this,

```
var MiddelEastCountriesArray = [['Benelux', 'NE'], ['Deutschland', 'DE'], ['France', 'FR'], ['Ireland', 'IE'], ['Italia', 'IE'], ['Nordics', 'NO'], ['Middle East', 'ME'], ['United Kingdom', 'UK']];

for(var i = 0; i < MiddelEastCountriesArray.length; i++) {
    document.write("<p><a href='http://www.test.com/" + MiddelEastCountriesArray[i][1] + "/default.aspx'>" + MiddelEastCountriesArray[i][0] + "</a></p>");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have made a small mistake in my posted code, I edited it. Please have a look again. I want to pass both values to the link. Thanks

Comment: @user3689990 Copy my above code and paste it in console and hit enter you will see the exact expected output

Comment: If he's only trying to print the second one of each inner loop this is the right way to do it but from what I understood he was trying to create links with both the country name and it's abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if it meets your requirement or not but if have an array of object then it won't be painful .

```
var MiddelEastCountriesArray = [{place:'Benelux',abbreviation:'NE'},{place:'Detuschland',abbreviation:'DE'}]
```

Now you can iterate over it in this way:

```
    MiddelEastCountriesArray.forEach(function(x){document.write("<p><a href='http://www.test.com/" + x.abbreviation + "/default.aspx'>" + x.place + "</a></p>");})
```